# Looking for an explantion for the official answer to SQLZOO NSS Tutorial #8

Tags: sql

There is a problem when I praticed in SQLZOO. The problem is as followed:

> #8 Show the institution, the total sample size and the number of computing students for institutions in Manchester for 'Q01'. (https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/NSS_Tutorial)

My answer is like:

```
SELECT institution,sum(sample),count(DISTINCT ukprn)
from nss
where institution like '%Manchester%'
AND question = 'Q01'
AND subject ='(8) Computer Science'
Group by institution;
```

The correct answer I can find on internet is like:

```
SELECT institution, SUM(sample), 
(SELECT sample FROM nss y
WHERE subject='(8) Computer Science'
AND x.institution = y.institution
AND question='Q01') AS comp
FROM nss x
WHERE question='Q01'
AND (institution LIKE '%Manchester%')
GROUP BY institution;
```

I don't know why I am wrong with my clause.
Why it uses sub-query in the SELECT section?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial is horrible, it took me half an hour to even understand one table structure and data, and this particular question is very poorly formulated, anyway, what they really want to see is two numbers, first:

total sample size for all students answered Q01 for each institution (total, not just for computer science), this can be solved via:

```
SELECT institution,sum(sample)
from nss
where institution like '%Manchester%'
AND question = 'Q01'
Group by institution;
```

now, second part, for each institution they want to see number of computer science students answered Q01, so we can add `case` into query:

```
SELECT institution,sum(sample),sum(case when subject ='(8) Computer Science' then sample else 0 end)
from nss
where institution like '%Manchester%'
AND question = 'Q01'
Group by institution;
```

this is correct answer, now to your question about query you found, it achieves the same without `case` by using subquery, which is also possible, but maybe a little bit slower

Comment: I agree with you. This exercise is horrible! I am a beginner and it took me for a long time and I still cannot figure it out.  Thank you for your answer, it is much easier to understand . I think we won't encounter this kind of question in real cases. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your filter on computer science is applied to both computed values.  But you don't want it for the sample size.

If I understand the question, you want:

```
select institution, sum(sample),
       count(distinct case when subject = '(8) Computer Science' then ukprn end)
from nss
where institution like '%Manchester%' and 
      question = 'Q01' 
group by institution;
```

A subquery seems overly complicated for the question.

Actually, I'm guessing that no one takes the survey more than once, so there are no duplicates for a given student.  In that case, `count(distinct)` is just wasted overhead, so use:

```
select institution, sum(sample),
       sum(case when subject = '(8) Computer Science' then 1 else 0 end)
from nss
where institution like '%Manchester%' and 
      question = 'Q01' 
group by institution;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT institution
      ,sum(sample)
      ,sum(IF (subject = '(8) Computer Science',sample,0)) as comp
 FROM nss
WHERE question='Q01'
  AND (institution LIKE '%Manchester%')
Group by 1
```

Comment: Answers that contain only code are generally considered to be poor quality. Take the [tour] and visit the [help] and learn how to use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Also, as far as I am aware, there is no `if` in standard SQL and since the question is not tagged with a specific DBMS, I believe that any answer should contain only standard SQL.